# What does "Couple Architecture Components Loosely" mean?

Tags: java

From other explanations of it, loose coupling is the idea of making interfaces for large classes that are used a lot, for example, if I had a class for players called "Player", I would make it an interface and use a class called "PlayerImpl" or something for the code.

According to Better Code Hub, that is wrong and the implementation class isn't loosely coupled. So which is it? Should loose coupled classes minimize the amount of calls to/from the class (if so why use static helper classes)? Should it use interfaces with implementation classes (so is Better Code Hub just completely wrong?)

Also, if an interface is meant to be extended alongside a class, should I re-declare all the methods to be used, not just used ones?

Comment: The title of this question is "What does 'Couple Architecture Components Loosely' mean?", but then the only question in the actual body of the question is "Also, if an interface is meant to be extended alongside a class, should I re-declare all the methods to be used, not just used ones?". So, that doesn't make sense; I think you meant to ask some other question in your question body, but forgot to do so.

Comment: Sorry, it's weird asking a non-code related question.